# Give an example of an operator on a finite dimensional vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra

Give an example of an operator on a finite-dimensional real vector space such that 0 is the only eigencvalue of T but T is not nilpotent.

I've been stuck on this problem for a while, the main example that comes to mind is the shift operator because the only eigenvalue of it is $\lambda = 0$ such that $T(z_1, \dots z_n) = (0, z_1, \dots, z_{n-1})$

However this is obviously nilpotent

So instead I tried an operator that rotates like this

$T(z_1, \dots z_n) = (z_n, z_1, \dots, z_{n-1})$

or flips them so that $T(z_1, \dots z_n) = (z_n, \dots, z_1)$

But neither of these have an eigenvalue of $lambda = 0$ because $z_1 \dots z_n$ would all have to be zero.

The differentiation map is also nilpotent.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

The result isn't true if $0$ is the only eigenvalue of $T$. This is because, then the characteristic equation for $T$ will be $x^n=0$, and by Cayley-Hamilton theorem, $T^n=0$ i.e. $T$ is nilpotent. I guess the question means that $T$ has only one real eigenvalue- which is $0$. The other eigenvalues are complex.

If that's the case then try to find a $3$x$3$ matrix which is similar to a diagonal matrix with diagonals $0,i,-i$. (This is easy).

Comment: The question states clearly that the vector space must be real and 0 is the only eigenvalue. However if the vector space is real, the other eigenvalues of T can still be complex correct?

Comment: @Soaps: yes: simplest example is the matric whose first row is $0,1$ and 2nd row is $-1,0$

Comment: What about the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} 0&-1&0\\  1&0&0 \\ 0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: @Hamou: here the only real eigenvalue is $0$, and the other two eigenvalues are $i,-i$. That's exactly what I said in the above answer.

Comment: @voldemort But $0$ is the only eigenvalue, and not nilpotent.

Comment: @Hamou: $0$ is NOT the only eigenvalue. $0$ is the only REAL eigenvalue. There's a difference :). I mentioned this case in my answer- this is probably what the book wants.

Comment: In the post it written : finite-dimensional real vector space. Hence we work in the real case $\Bbb K=\Bbb R$.

Comment: Clarification: $0$ is the ONLY EIGENVALUE. Is it impossible then? I'm confused because this is a practice problem in my book it says to give an example, not prove or disprove or anything like that. V is a real vector space with only one eigenvalue for T, which is $0$.

Comment: @Soaps: As I proved in my answer- it's not possible then. However, the book probably wants Hamou's answer- see my second paragraph in the answer above.

Answer (score -1):

Take $V=\Bbb R^n$ ($n\geq 3$) real vector space , and $(e_1,\ldots, e_n)$ a canonical basis, and $T\in \mathcal(L)(V)$ defined by: $T(e_1)=e_2$ , $T(e_2)=-e_1$, and $T(e_k)=0$ for $k\geq 3$. $0$ is the only eigenvalue of $T$ and $T$ is not nilpotent.

Comment: $0$ is not the only eigenvalue. $0$ is the only real eigenvalue.

Comment: When we work in $\Bbb K$ vector space the eigenvalues are by definition in  $ \Bbb K$.

Comment: Eigenvalues are by definition the solution of the characteristic equation: they need not lie in the base field. They lie in an algebraic closure of the base field.

Comment: See this link for example: http://math.mit.edu/linearalgebra/ila0601.pdf

Comment: What mean then that $f(v)=\lambda v$ (if $\lambda\notin \Bbb K$)? see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors)

Comment: we want solution to $f(v)=\lambda v$. The solution need not exist in the base field. But that DOES NOT mean that the matrix has no eigenvalues. For example the rotation by $90$ degrees matrix has no real eigenvalues- but that doesn't mean that it has no eigenvalues.

Comment: In the $\Bbb K$ vector space , what does it mean  $\lambda.v$ if $\lambda\notin \Bbb K$ (this external product is not defined)

Comment: $\lambda$ is a variable. What does it mean for $x^2+1=0$? The polynomial $x^2+1$ has two roots. However, none of them are in $\mathbb{R}$. Would you say that the polynomial has no root? Most mathematicians wouldn't. Note that this is the same question anyway- eigenvalues being roots of some polynomial (characteristic polynomial).